# NHibernate DTO Parent child relation

Tags: nhibernate

I have som entities and now want to make some DTO´s based on there entities using nhibernate.

I have a Service - Allocation -Ressource where allocation describes how the ressource is allocated for the service.

I want a DTO like

ServiceDTO
-Name
-RessourceDTO

where RessourceDTO also has a name.

In the examples I have see for NHibernate projection/DTO you either use properties or constructor. If I use The Constructor approach I would have something like

ServiceDTO(Name, List

But I can't figure out how to make this work.

Another approach is to extract all the services and then loop through them and hit the database each time, or extract a larger result and then make the DTO's

What is the best approach? I going to hide all of this inside a repository.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public ServiceDTO GetDTOFor(int Id);
{
    var service = Session.CreateCriteria<Service>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id)
        .SetFetchMode("Resources", fetchmode.eager)    // eager load resources
        .uniqueResult<Service>();

    return new ServiceDTO(service.Name, service.Resources.ToList())  // Copy the Resources
}
```